# Add latest Youtube videos on main page

Tags: youtube

Is there any ways to get latest Youtube videos from my Youtube channel and show theme in a video gallery on Wordpress page?

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats more a youtube than a wordpress question. But you can write a simple shortcode function and add it to your site.

```
// Add Shortcode
   function custom_youtubeapishortcode()
   {
     $playlistid = "XXXX";
     $apikey = "XXXX";


     $curl = curl_init();

     curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
     CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=".$playlistid."&maxResults=1&key=".$apikey."",
     CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
     CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
     CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
     CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
     CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
     CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
     CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
     "Accept: */*",
     "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate",
     "Cache-Control: no-cache",
     "Connection: keep-alive",
     "Host: www.googleapis.com",
     "cache-control: no-cache"
   ),
  ));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    $array = json_decode($response, true);
    return apply_filters('the_content', "https://youtu.be/".$array['items']['0']['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId']);
}
 }
 add_shortcode('youtubeapishortcode', 'custom_youtubeapishortcode');
```

Than you should get a api key for youtube from google developers :https://console.developers.google.com/

Add the api Key and the youtube playlist ID to the code and add it to your functions.php

Call the shortcode on any page:

```
 [youtubeapishortcode]
```

Comment: Thank you, it works for me but still just one video appear not the whole list!

Comment: you can modify the url to get more than one video by changing the parameter maxResults=1 to the number you need. As the result you get a array ($array = json_decode($response, true);, you can loop through to show more videos.